# Why this c++ code is giving me segmentation fault error on runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, segmentation-fault

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int max=500008;
   long long cordx[max],cordy[max];
   char type[max];
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   for(int m=0;m<n;m++)
       cin>>type[m]>>cordx[m]>>cordy[m];
   return 0;
}
```

This code is giving me a Segmentation Fault error on runtime.

But when I change my code like this:

```
for(m=0;m<n;m++)
    cin>>cordx[m];
```

It is not giving me any error.

Its giving me error only when I try to input like this:

```
 cin>>type[m]>>cordx[m]>>cordy[m];
```

Comment: Perhaps the arrays are too big for the stack

Comment: Try Decreasing size of the array, Does the problem still persists?

Comment: It is likely that the regions of `cordx` being written to, maybe all of it, fits inside the available storage and only when the program is writing to the next variable the program travels out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

A long long is typically 8 bytes. `cordx` and `cordy` each request space for 500008 of them in Automatic  storage. That's about 8 MB storage and either far over or coming up on the maximum Automatic storage available. The typical PC uses a stack for Automatic storage and the stack is usually between 1 and 10 MB in size.

Solutions are to use `std::vector` to allocate storage from the much larger Dynamic storage or define the variables to be allocated in Static storage (make them `static` or define them globally).

Additionally, the user may specify an `n` that is greater than 500008 and force access out of bounds.